# PHP accessing JSON response and printing

Tags: php, json

I have the following code and just want to access the information inside of the following and print `Status`

`"Email": { "Status": "in-queue" }`

I'm really new to PHP so I apologize for any errors, learning for a class.

```
{
    "APIResponse": {
        "ResponseStatus": 1,
        "Email": {
            "EmailSid": "12893712893789",
            "SentEmails": "my@email.com",
            "Date": "2017-02-07 22:53:26",
            "Subject": "700message",
            "Status": "in-queue",
            "TotalEmailSent": 1,
            "TotalPrize": "0.0100",
            "ApiVersion": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to do this in JavaScript however it seems a bit differrent for PHP.

Any help is appreciated thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick PHP example of how to convert your JSON string into an array and display a value:

`$json = '{
    "APIResponse": {
        "ResponseStatus": 1,
        "Email": {
            "EmailSid": "12893712893789",
            "SentEmails": "my@email.com",
            "Date": "2017-02-07 22:53:26",
            "Subject": "700message",
            "Status": "in-queue",
            "TotalEmailSent": 1,
            "TotalPrize": "0.0100",
            "ApiVersion": "2"
        }
    }
}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['APIResponse']['Email']['Status'];`

Note how each child node becomes a child in the associative array.  You can also do a `print_r($array);` to see the entire structure in the native PHP associative array format.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $json = '{
    "APIResponse": {
        "ResponseStatus": 1,
        "Email": {
            "EmailSid": "12893712893789",
            "SentEmails": "my@email.com",
            "Date": "2017-02-07 22:53:26",
            "Subject": "700message",
            "Status": "in-queue",
            "TotalEmailSent": 1,
            "TotalPrize": "0.0100",
            "ApiVersion": "2"
        }
    }
}';


// if this API response's JSON is being stored as a string type local variable decode it first.

$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);

//Optional but helps when programing var_dump($decoded_json); Use this to help visualize the nested array variables you need to access.

// Use each array key to walk into and access the desired value

echo $decoded_json['APIResponse']['Email']['Status'];


 ?>
```

*Edit to account for errors, based on the question in your comment:

While still being sure to first decode the Json as mentioned above, the below should allow you to access these values.

```
echo $decoded_json['APIResponse']['Errors']['Error'][0]['Code'];

echo $decoded_json['APIResponse']['Errors']['Error'][0]['Message'];
```

Lastly, and more as advice if you ever do get stumped. Try just accessing one array at a time starting with the outermost and working your way in, always helps me!

Comment: What about the array inside of this? I want to echo `"Code"`

```
    {
        "APIResponse": {
            "ResponseStatus": 0,
            "Errors": {
                "Error": [
                    {
                        "Code": "Error code 5001",
                        "Message": "Please enter a correctly formatted 'To' email address.",
                        "MoreInfo": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```


Last question, thanks guys so much!